# VB.NET MVC Get vs Post how do i design my page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have a VB.NET mvc view form that has 3 parameters and 2 buttons and I not sure how to design my page.

Button 1 is essentially a GET - suppose to run a sql query and return a dataset (multiple tables).
Button 2 is essentially a PUT - suppose to run a sql update statement (multiple updates).

CustomModel includes my 3 parameters as Properties and I have included the Required Attribute on all.

How do I design so that the Required attributes are respected.
I.e. my ViewInfo method is being reached even if the parameter inputs are blank.

Do I declare ViewInfo with the HttpGet and my UpdateInfo with HttpPut attribute. Do I need the parameter declarations in my ViewInfo method?
Is my @Html.BeginForm(...) declaration correct?

VB.NET Model class:

```
Public Class CustomModel
    <Required(ErrorMessage:="Parameter 1 is required"),
    Display(Name:="Parameter 1:")>
    Public Property Parameter1 As String

    <Required(ErrorMessage:="Parameter 2 is required"),
    Display(Name:="Parameter 2:")>
    Public Property Parameter2 As String

    <Required(ErrorMessage:="Parameter 3 is required"),
    Display(Name:="Parameter 3:")>
    Public Property Parameter3 As Integer

    Public Sub New(Parameter1 As String, Parameter2 As String, Parameter3 As Integer)
        Me.Parameter1 = Parameter1
        Me.Parameter2 = Parameter2
        Me.Parameter3 = Parameter3
    End Sub

    Public Property Info As DataSet = New DataSet
End Class
```

VB.NET Controller:

```
Function Index() As ActionResult
    ViewBag.ShowView = False
    Return View()
End Function

Function ViewInfo(Parameter1 As String, Parameter2 As String, Parameter3 As Integer)
    Dim result As New CustomModel(Parameter1, Parameter2, Parameter3)
    If ModelState.IsValid Then
        result.Info = GetInfo(Parameter1, Parameter2, Parameter3)
    End If
    ViewBag.ShowView = True
    Return View("Index", result)
End Function

Function UpdateInfo(Parameter1 As String, Parameter2 As String, Parameter3 As Integer)
    Dim result As New CustomModel(Parameter1, Parameter2, Parameter3)
    If ModelState.IsValid Then
        result.Info = UpdateInfo(Parameter1, Parameter2, Parameter3)
    End If
    ViewBag.ShowView = True
    Return View("Index", result)
End Function
```

HTML View

```
@ModelType CustomModel
...
@Using (Html.BeginForm("ViewInfo", "Home", Nothing, FormMethod.Post))
    ...
    @Html.LabelFor(...)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(...)
    ...
    <button type=button>View</button>
    <button type=submit>Update</button>
End Using
```

Output:

```
@If ViewBag.Show Then
    // Multiple WebGrid calls ???
End If
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question but here's one thing: In your view you have a form that's going to `POST` to `ViewInfo` actionresult/function.
However, your controller only has one function titled `ViewInfo` and it is by default processing a `GET` request. Either change your formmethod to `GET` or declare your function as a `POST` request  handler.

Comment: I tried both suggestions and neither work. Both suggestions my Required attributes are not honoured, i.e. no validation is done. My rendered TextBox for the first input is: <input name="Parameter1" class="form-control input-lg" id="Parameter1" type="text" value="" data-val-required="Parameter 1 is required" data-val="true">. Second option I had to make my View button a submit button otherwise nothing is called.

Comment: Note I am trying to avoid client side jquery to validate however if I have to I will.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to get me on my way finally.

I did not realise the default layout page behind the scenes does not include the validation javascript file so I had to add to my specific view file:

```
@Section scripts
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
End Section
```

Is there something you have to do so that this file is automatically brought in or is what I have done is correct you have to manually include it in either the layout or the specific view where you need it?